# How would I reset my Chosen select menu after creating a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

How does one reset a [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) field after resource is created by Javascript?

I create a dog and can get the regular form fields to reset but not the select menu using the Chosen plugin:

**dogs/create.js.erb**

```
$('#dogs').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@dog)) %>');
$('.add-dog-form > form')[0].reset();
```

This is successful reset, just not with the  chosen menu which is called from my **application.js**:

```
jQuery( function($) {
    // Chosen Select Menu
    $('.category-select').chosen().trigger("liszt:updated");
});
```

Than my form:

```
<%= form_for(@dog, :remote => true) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name, "Name" %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :category, "Categories" %>
  <%= f.select :category_ids, Category.all.collect {|c| [c.name, c.id]}, {}, { :multiple => true, :class => "category-select" } %>
<% end %>
```

So again, how does one reset a [Chosen plugin](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/) field after resource is created by Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**dogs/create.js.erb**

```
$('#dogs').prepend('<%= escape_javascript(render(@dog)) %>');
$('.add-dog-form > form')[0].reset();
$('.category-select').chosen().trigger("liszt:updated");
```

You basically have to trigger the reset again inside create.js.erb.